Monitor Refresh Rate Issue: 60Hz Before Login, 75Hz After Login on Multiple Linux-OS and DEs
I recently purchased a new monitor and encountered an issue regarding the refresh rate. When logging into Arch Linux with KDE Plasma on Wayland, the monitor settings indicate a 60Hz refresh rate, but after logging in, it automatically changes to 75Hz.
This persists across various operating systems and desktop environments, including Linux Mint, Ubuntu, and Debian, and different desktop environments like Xfce, Wayland and gnome, also with different display connections such as HDMI and VGA to HDMI.
Interestingly, when using HDMI alone, the monitor also displays a green tint before system authorization, which resolves upon login.
Windows 11 on a separate partition functions flawlessly, suggesting the graphics card may not be the culprit. This situation perplexes me, as I'm uncertain whether the problem stems from the monitor, HDMI port, GPU, VGA connection, or system settings.
Another problem. As soon as I log into the system using this monitor, my Splash Screen animation does not work. That is, the animation that comes up, after log-in, it does not work. As soon as I changed the monitor to my old one, the animation is displayed on the old monitor. I am just saying this because there are many such strange nuances that confuse me.
I've been digging through my BIOS settings but couldn't find an option to change the refresh rate from 60Hz to 75Hz during system boot. Despite my efforts, I was unable to locate such a setting.
Additionally, I've spent a considerable amount of time searching various forums and using Google, trying different configurations. At one point, my system even crashed, and I had to reinstall everything. I've tried numerous solutions without success.
I suspect the problem might be related to my monitor since it's a relatively inexpensive model. However, I haven't had the opportunity to test a modern monitor that also supports 75Hz to confirm if the issue is indeed with the monitor.
Despite trying many different approaches, I still haven't found a solution.
Sorry, I'm not even sure if I'm posting in the right place about this issue because I can't figure out what the problem is.
Monitor - 2E Monitor B2423B;
GPU - GeForce GTX 1660 Super;
OS - Arch Linux, KDE Plasma on Wayland.

The green tint might be the display mis-detecting the use of a HDR color mode (false positive). With luck, fixing the refresh rate issue might fix the green tint too.
Regarding the splash screen animation: if you are using multiple displays, have you selected one of them as the "primary" display? I think I once had odd things like that happen when I had no primary display selected. But that was a few Debian relases ago, so might not be true any more (assuming my memory is even correct).
When not logged in, the GUI login manager attempts to display the login screen on all connected displays; when logging in, the display switches to per-user settings instead. That would explain the refresh rate switch. To make the display always use the 75 Hz refresh rate, first log in and make sure the display is set the way you want; then go to System Settings -> Startup and Shutdown -> Login Screen. At the bottom of the window, there should be a button Apply Plasma Settings.... In other words, it will make the display settings of the login screen be the same as the settings of your current login session. Click on that button, then click Apply to confirm. You may have to type in your password, since this is a system-wide change.

I'm also sure that the only constant issue is the 60Hz input. If i fix it, then I can basically use HDMI instead of VGA-HDMI. I already tried "Apply Plasma Settings" - it didn't help. It's a very strange situation, but I just want to understand what exactly is causing it so I know whether to change the monitor, the video card, or continue fiddling with the settings.
